# LAMP Compute Engine changes IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I moved my PHP application to the Google Cloud platform since Google is my friend. I'm very happy with it, but my IP keeps changing which is pretty annoying since my platform needs to be whitelisted on several feed servers.

Can I do something about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using [ephemeral ip address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#ephemeraladdress) which provide connectivity from outside but these addresses can change over time. What you're looking for is [static external ip address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#reservedaddress) which never change (until you explicitly release it).

Go to the [Create a new external static IP address](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/addresses/add?_ga=1.227246751.322142413.1454938549) page to create a new static external IP. Once created, you will need to assign this new static IP address to your instance:

- In the Cloud Platform Console, go to the [VM Instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=1.25772607.322142413.1454938549) page.
- Click the Create instance button.
- On the Create a new instance page, fill in the desired properties for your instance.
- Expand the Management, disk, networking, SSH keys section.
- Click Networking.
- Under External IP, select a static external IP address.
- Click the Create button to create the instance.